# How to change the worker name of Dask cluster?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I am asking this for local cluster.

Here is the code for getting the address and the name of the worker:

```
def f():
   worker = get_worker().name  
   return worker

client.run(f)
```

Output:

```
{'tcp://127.0.0.1:58709': 0,
'tcp://127.0.0.1:58710': 2,
'tcp://127.0.0.1:58711': 1}
```

It is in the dictionary. The key is the address and the value is the name of the worker. is there any way to assign the worker's name while creating the client? or any way around.

just changing the dictionary value doesn't change the original of the worker.

**My motivation behind this:**
*My goal is to create a worker and assign the preprocessing task to that. After the create two models let's say logistic reg and random forest classifier.

and Now I want to scale up the worker using the scale method. and assign the model training for two models on two new workers.

But the thing is how will I identify which worker is the new worker? Because the worker name is like worker_0, worker_1, worker_2. Is the new worker which is created either worker_0 or worker_1? How do identify the new worker name?

I do believe that new worker names are in an incremental fashion.
But I need proof to validate my reason. That's why I thought It better to change the name. So that I can keep track of the worker more easily.*

Reference for the original question: [How to get the worker name in dask cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72951003/how-to-get-the-worker-name-in-dask-cluster/72956283?noredirect=1#comment128877467_72956283)

Comment: Please link original question and specify that this is for a LocalCluster

Comment: I have made the changes that you have asked for. Eagerly waiting for your kind response.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the current implementation of LocalCluster does not allow you to set the name via the constructor. You could propose a change to the codebase via a PR.

It raises the question, what do you wish to achieve with the names? You already have both a unique sequence number (the current `.name`) and unique UUID-based ID for every worker, as well as the workers' unique TCP addresses.

Finally - and this is untested - you could plausibly use `client.run` together with `get_worker()` to *set* the `.name` attribute dynamically at runtime, should you wish. The following would set the name attribute for the specific worker (as a TCP address) given in the workers= list.

```
def set_name(name):
    get_worker().name = name

client.run(set_name, "name1", workers=[..])
```

-EDIT-

After providing motivation, I believe this question is not actually asking what you want - maybe make a new a new question. Perhaps `clinet.who_has` is what you want, but your workflow isn't clear to me.

Comment: It is not possible to write a long comment. I have added my motivation behind achieving this in the question description. Please have a read. Any suggestion or advice to achieve that would be a great help.